# Collision of method name between C Socket & Omnet++

Tags: c++, sockets, omnet++

I want to use sockets inside my network simulation done with Omnet++, i am getting a collision of method name between:

- send() method of Socket.
- send() method defined by Omnet++, that allow
  exchange of msg between simulation modules.

The compiler recognize only send() method defined by Omnet++.

How can i resolve it ?

Thank you,

**EDIT**

In order to make it more clear, i will past a copy of my code:

GeoTraCIMobility.cc (CPP Code)

```
#include <limits>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
//#include <cstring>      // Needed for memset
//#include <sys/socket.h> // Needed for the socket functions
//#include <netdb.h>      // Needed for the socket functions
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#include "mobility/geoTraCI/GeoTraCIMobility.h"

Define_Module(GeoTraCIMobility);

namespace {
    const double MY_INFINITY = (std::numeric_limits<double>::has_infinity ? std::numeric_limits<double>::infinity() : std::numeric_limits<double>::max());

    double roadIdAsDouble(std::string road_id) {
        std::istringstream iss(road_id);
        double d;
        if (!(iss >> d)) return MY_INFINITY;
        return d;
    }
}

void GeoTraCIMobility::Statistics::initialize()
{
    firstRoadNumber = MY_INFINITY;
    startTime = simTime();
    totalTime = 0;
    stopTime = 0;
    minSpeed = MY_INFINITY;
    maxSpeed = -MY_INFINITY;
    totalDistance = 0;
    totalCO2Emission = 0;
}

//OTHERS FUNCTIONS

// Function that create a socket and send data
void GeoTraCIMobility::requestingFromPyServer()
{
    std::string HOST = "127.0.0.1";
    int PORT = 19999;
    int MAX_BUFFER = 1024;

      int connectionFd, rc, index = 0, limit = MAX_BUFFER;
      struct sockaddr_in servAddr, localAddr;
      char buffer[MAX_BUFFER+1];


      memset(&servAddr, 0, sizeof(servAddr));
      servAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
      servAddr.sin_port = htons(PORT);
      servAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(HOST.c_str());

      // Create socket
      connectionFd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

      /* bind any port number */
      localAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
      localAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
      localAddr.sin_port = htons(0);

      rc = bind(connectionFd,
          (struct sockaddr *) &localAddr, sizeof(localAddr));

      // Connect to Server
      connect(connectionFd,
          (struct sockaddr *)&servAddr, sizeof(servAddr));

      // Send request to Server
      std::string req= "ShortestPath_297162704_82660198";
      sprintf( buffer, "%s", req.c_str() );

      // UNRECOGNIZED SEND METHOD 
      send(connectionFd, buffer, strlen(buffer), 0 );
      // UNRECOGNIZED SEND METHOD

      close(connectionFd);

      printf("Client closed.\n");
}
```

GeoTraCIMobility.cc inherits from cSimpleModule the following send methods:

cSimpleModule.h

```
/**
 * Sends a message through the gate given with its ID.
 */
int send(cMessage *msg, int gateid)  {return sendDelayed(msg, SIMTIME_ZERO, gateid);}

/**
 * Sends a message through the gate given with its name and index
 * (if multiple gate).
 */
int send(cMessage *msg, const char *gatename, int gateindex=-1)  {return sendDelayed(msg, SIMTIME_ZERO, gatename, gateindex);}

/**
 * Sends a message through the gate given with its pointer.
 */
int send(cMessage *msg, cGate *outputgate)  {return sendDelayed(msg, SIMTIME_ZERO, outputgate);}
```

Comment: Since Omnet++ is a C++ framework, doesn't it use classes or namespaces? Don't pull in symbols in the global namespace with the `using` keyword unless you know there are no collisions. Only pull in symbols you know to be safe, or use namespace aliasing if you think the namespace name is to long.

Comment: I didn't understand what you said here !? I looked for a manner to call the send() method of Sockets, by enclosing it with a namespace, after that i remember that there is no namespace with C. Also, i can't enclose my code in a manner to avoid the use of this method (send() method of Omnet++), since it is an herited method

Comment: Omnet++ is a C++ framework, so it can't be used in a C program. Also, Omnet++ uses an `omnetcpp` namespace (if I read the documentation correctly), so if there is an `omnetcpp::send` function you should use that. ***Don't*** do `using namespace omnetcpp;` as that will pull in all symbols from the `omnetcpp` namespace into the global namespace, and you will have a collision with e.g. `send`.

Comment: Also, if the Omnet++ `send` function is an *inherited* function, then that means it is a *member function* inside a class, and not a standalone global function. Then there is no collision, as you need an instance of the class to be able to call the Omnet++ `send` function. Maybe you [need to relearn basic C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `::send(...)` to access the global function in an OMNeT++ model. Otherwise the `send()` method inhertited from the cSimpleModule will be called.